# How to query Certificate Transparency Logs Servers with your own API?

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, x509certificate, merkle-tree, cert

I'm trying to query the certificate transparency logs servers out there. I have read that there are several of them out there, but I don't know what is the correct "domain" or "IP" to query them.

I have read the RFC6962 and there are several procedures how to add certificates to the logs or to retrieve them, like:

4.1.  Add Chain to Log

```
POST https://<log server>/ct/v1/add-chain
```

4.2.  Add PreCertChain to Log

```
POST https://<log server>/ct/v1/add-pre-chain
```

4.3.  Retrieve Latest Signed Tree Head

```
GET https://<log server>/ct/v1/get-sth
```

4.4.  Retrieve Merkle Consistency Proof between Two Signed Tree Heads

```
GET https://<log server>/ct/v1/get-sth-consistency
```

4.5.  Retrieve Merkle Audit Proof from Log by Leaf Hash

```
GET https://<log server>/ct/v1/get-proof-by-hash
```

4.6.  Retrieve Entries from Log

```
GET https://<log server>/ct/v1/get-entries
```

I'm not sure where to find the list of "log server" values to implement my API.

Do you have any updated information about where to find the actual domains to query the CT Logs? Or the domains or subdomains to query specifically?

Comment: https://certificate.transparency.dev/